# On the property of $F(y) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{1}{(\sinh|x|)^\alpha} \frac{1}{(\sinh|x-y|)^{\beta}} dx$

Tags: integration, asymptotics

For $\alpha,\beta>0, \alpha+\beta<1$, and $y\geq 0$, define a function
$$F(y) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{1}{(\sinh|x|)^\alpha} \frac{1}{(\sinh|x-y|)^{\beta}} dx.$$
Note that $F$ is well-defined, by considering that $\frac{1}{\sinh|x|} \approx 1/|x|$ for small $|x|$.

**My question**: Is $F(y) - F(0) = O(y)$ as $y\to 0$?

What I tried is that, I proved that $F$ is $C^1$ at $y>0$. (However, this is not enough to answer my question, since my question deals with the behavior at $y=0$.

To show that $F$ is $C^1$ at $y>0$, naive differentiation fails, since
$$\frac{d}{dy} \frac{1}{(\sinh|x-y|)^{\beta}} = \pm \beta  \frac{\cosh|x-y|}{(\sinh|x-y|)^{\beta+1}}$$
is not integrable as a function of $x$. Hence, I used the trick of substituting $x \to xy$:
$$F(y) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{|y|}{(\sinh|yx|)^\alpha (\sinh|y(x-1)|)^\beta} dx.$$
Then, we can differentiate the integrand, since for example
$$\frac{d}{dy} \frac{1}{(\sinh|yx|)^\alpha} = -\alpha \frac{|x|\cosh|yx|}{(\sinh|yx|)^{\alpha+1}} $$
is integrable, due to additional factor of $|x|$. Of course, one has to justify the change of differentiation and integration, but this can be done by the estimate
$$\frac{1}{\sinh|x|} \leq \frac{2}{|x|} e^{-|x|}.$$
(I actually believe that $F$ is $C^\infty$ in $y>0$, but the calculation, in particular justifying the change of two limits, becomes very messy.)

Comment: $F(y) - F(0)$ is not $O(y)$. Take $\alpha = \beta = 1/4$,
$$f(y, x) =
\operatorname {csch}^\alpha |x| \operatorname {csch}^\beta |x - y|, \\
g(y, x) = |x|^{-\alpha} |x - y|^{-\beta} \big[ |x| < 1 \big].$$
The integral of $f - g$ is a constant plus $o(\sqrt y)$, while the integral of $g$ is a constant plus $\Theta(\sqrt y)$.

Comment: @Maxim Thanks for your comment! I think the second estimate on $g$ is obtained by substitution $x=x'y$, but I cannot figure out how one proves that $f-g$ is a constant plus $o(\sqrt y)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $y>0$, making the substitution $x=yt$, we get $$F(y)-F(0)=y\int_{-\infty}^\infty\sinh^{-\alpha}(y|t|)\big[\sinh^{-\beta}(y|t-1|)-\sinh^{-\beta}(y|t|)\big]\,dt,$$ so that, using the [dominated convergence theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem), $$\lim_{y\to 0}\frac{F(y)-F(0)}{y^{1-\alpha-\beta}}=\Lambda(\alpha,\beta):=\int_{-\infty}^\infty|t|^{-\alpha}(|t-1|^{-\beta}-|t|^{-\beta})\,dt.$$ In fact, this integral can be expressed in terms of the [beta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function): $$\Lambda(\alpha,\beta)=-\pi\frac{\tan(\alpha\pi/2)+\tan(\beta\pi/2)}{(1-\alpha-\beta)\mathrm{B}(\alpha,\beta)}.$$ Thus $F(y)-F(0)=\Theta(y^{1-\alpha-\beta})$ as $y\to 0$.